# Syntax error near unexpected token done when looping a multi-statement line

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have the following code as part of a larger file (assume `${tools_urls}`, `${tempFolder}` are global variables)

```
download_tools()
{
    for i in ${tools_urls}; do
        wget --no-check-certificate --directory-prefix=${tempFolder} ${i} || { echo "download failed" ; exit 3}
    done
}
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token 'done'
```

However, if I remove the `|| { echo "download failed" ; exit 3}` part of the loop, it works.

Why is this the case? I can't see anything wrong with my code, and I can't find similar examples that involve multiple statements in one line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping) with curly braces must have semicolons after each command in it:

```
{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }
```

So change it to:

```
... || { echo "download failed" ; exit 3; }
```

Notice that the space after the last command is needed:

> The braces are *reserved words*, so they must be separated from the *list* (the commands) by blanks or other shell metacharacters.

---

Also, notice that you should quote your variables:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --directory-prefix="${tempFolder}" "${i}"
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Here's what I don't get though: somewhere else in my code, I have a similar compound command, but it's not inside a for loop. If I put a semicolon like in your example, I get a syntax error! Why is a semicolon needed only inside a for loop, but not outside of it?

Comment: And thanks for noticing my other unrelated mistake with the quotes. Appreciate it! Still learning bash...

Comment: @9a3eedi Can you post that whole compound command, where you get the syntax error?

Comment: @BinaryZebra I added the note thanks, and good point